# Why is it that I add ORG.mongodb.smth to dependencies and then import COM.mongodb.smth?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, import, casbah

I'm doing this from within code in a Scala/SBT project, but I assume this question should equally well apply to Java code.

In `build.sbt` I have:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.3"
```

but then in the code, I need to import for example:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient
```

I would try googling this, but I have no idea what's the question I should ask from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the package structure for the 2.x java driver.  That's moving under org.mongodb for the core of the 3.x driver with a driver-compat module still under the com.mongodb namespace.

Answer (score 0):

the SBT or the MAVEN package's name is org.mongodb but inside the dependency jar packages start with com.mongodb

may be a legacy naming error or due to the fact of the separation between the commercial mongodb entity and the community project it self.

I just added casbah within my pom and got the com.mongodb package as well.